# Adding shadows to png images or removing backgbround and keeping the shadow

Tags: python, image-processing

I have a set of a few thousand imgages with white backgrounds and shadows, generated with AI. I need the white background to be transparent but the shadows to still be there.
When i remove the background, with the different ways ive tried it also removes the shadow. I either need a way to remove the white background and keep the shadow or a way to add good looking shadows to the images with transparent backgrounds.

Ive tried to remove the background, this also removes the shadow usually, but keeps the object.

For removing the background, i used rembg's remove function.
This removes most of the background, which is wanted, but also removes the shadow.

Whats the better way to go about this, remvoe shadows and add them after, or try to cut the background and keep the shadows. Would upload image examples but it server errors

Comment: What is your question? Please see [ask] first

Comment: Please share your code with the results you obtain

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.